# зависимое слово в словосочетании

Tags: синтаксис

Помогите определить главное слово и зависимое слово в словосочетании: сладкого печенья.

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае наблюдается согласование — вид подчинительной связи. При согласовании главным словом обычно является имя существительное, а в роли зависимого выступает либо имя прилагательное, либо причастие. Например: лазурное небо (прил. + сущ.), звонящий телефон (прич. + сущ.). В вашем случае *печенья* — это главное слово, а *сладкого* — зависимое. Характерным признаком согласования является то, что при изменении главного слова зависимое тоже поддается изменению. Например: просторный автомобиль, просторного автомобиля (Р.п.), просторному автомобилю (Д.п.).

Answer (score 0):

Главное слово: "печенья", зависимое - "сладкого". В словосочетании с существительным и прилагательным зависимым является прилагательное.